# Get name of connected device in Web Serial API on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, arduino, serial-port

As per [Chrome Platform Status](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884928#c148) Web Serial API is now state of shipping since Chrome V89.

I work on a Universal Serial Communication App, which allows to connect to a user selected serial port. After a `let port = await navigator.serial.requestPort()` the user selects a port from the list presented by chrome. This list contains names for the devices. Connecting the chosen port with `port.open(conSettings)` is no problem.

But **how can i get the NAME of the selected port/device** (from the shown list) using the Web Serial API? This is needed to show a status like "connected to ...". Without this it is confusing if you have multiple tabs with different ports open.

Comment: I don't think you can, at this point. `SerialPort.getInfo()` returns `usbProductId` and `usbVendorId` for USB ports and nothing (on my Win10 box) for built-in ports. Maybe this data will be available in the future: https://github.com/WICG/serial/issues/128#issuecomment-795870509

Comment: thanks @Johnny Mopp. This is the same post, which i stumbled upon in the last minutes ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this post](https://github.com/WICG/serial/issues/128#issuecomment-795870509), from March, the 10th 2021, from reillyeon (which is a Google chromium software engineer for usb and serial). He says it is **planed to add** an ID to the return of `getInfo()`, which can be used to remember and reconnect later to a still used device.

At the end of [this other post](https://github.com/WICG/serial/issues/19#issuecomment-761275669) he writes, he plans to *"introduce a random identifier"*, instead of *"USB product name or serial number strings"*, because *"concerns about fingerprinting"*.

**So it looks like, at this time there is nothing and it is also not planed to return a device name.** But when this would be implemented, it would be possible to save this ID in combination with a user supplied name for the device.

My question anyhow: Is fingerpriting a problem, when the user was still requested and has allowed the access to the device?

Comment: Argh this is disappointing! I was surprised to find that no commonly used name (e.g. `Arduino (COM3)` or `Arduino (/dev/ttyUSB0)` is provided from `getInfo()`, just two IDs. The name really helps users identify what they are connected to.